# combining rows with similar range of values in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

[image]

I have this data frame as seen below and I am trying to group by a range of time so everything from 00:01 - 00:59 is in one row (count is summed for all those rows)and then the next row is everything from 01:00 - 01:59 and the next is 2:00 - 2:59 etc so that there are 24 rows instead of a couple thousand... any ideas?

Comment: Could you post an example reproducible, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping by a substring of the column 'Time'.

```py
df.groupby([df['Time'].str[0:2]]).agg({'Count':'sum'})
```